# Rotation smooth in editor but isn't in device

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a 3D object that I want to rotate with mouse/finger swipe, so I made the script below.

The object's rotation looks smooth on editor, but when playing the game on real device (android), the rotation didn't follow the finger movement immediately, it takes some milliseconds to follow finger, it isn't smooth and the controls become hard and frustrating!

```
float sensitivity = 0.8f;
Vector2 firstPressPos;
Vector2 secondPressPos;

void Update()
{

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        //save began touch 2d point
        firstPressPos = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y);
    }

    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        //save ended touch 2d point
        secondPressPos = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y);

        if (firstPressPos != secondPressPos)
        {
            float RotX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
            float RotY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
            transform.RotateAround(Vector3.up, RotX);
            transform.RotateAround(Vector3.right, -RotY);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could try the Input.touch directly and using it from there. Then you can detect number of touches, and then also when press began, and stopped, etc. I had written something similar years ago, i'll see if i can find it. (This is in lieu of Input.GetMouseButton*)

Comment: @ApolloSOFTWARE Could you please show me how to apply that in my script? or just show me an example

Comment: -> What kind of device are you using to test with? It could be the processing/gpu power of your android device vs the tris and polys of your scene rendered. Maybe your device is simply getting overwhelmed? Unity3D has the guidelines posted in a few places (different per droid). For example, on my Pixel 3 I can run this smoothly with lots of polys/tris. However on my Samsung Galaxy S4 mini, the same scene is choppy. –

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code

```
// Screen Touches
    Vector2?[] oldTouchPositions = {
        null,
        null
    };
    // Rotation Speed
    public float rotSpeed = 0.5f;

    public void Update()
    {
        if (Input.touchCount == 0)
        {
            oldTouchPositions[0] = null;
            oldTouchPositions[1] = null;
        }
        else if (Input.touchCount == 1)
        {
            if (oldTouchPositions[0] == null || oldTouchPositions[1] != null)
            {
                oldTouchPositions[0] = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
                oldTouchPositions[1] = null;
            }
            else
            {
                Vector2 newTouchPosition = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
                float distanceX = (oldTouchPositions[0] - newTouchPosition).Value.x;
                float distanceY = (oldTouchPositions[0] - newTouchPosition).Value.y;

                float rotX = distanceX * rotSpeed * Mathf.Deg2Rad;
                float rotY = distanceY * rotSpeed * Mathf.Deg2Rad;


                transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, rotX * 5, Space.Self);
                transform.Rotate(Vector3.left, rotY * 5, Space.Self);


                oldTouchPositions[0] = newTouchPosition;

            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (oldTouchPositions[1] == null)
            {
                oldTouchPositions[0] = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
                oldTouchPositions[1] = Input.GetTouch(1).position;
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a script I found a few years back that manipulates X axis spin with Mouse or Touches. It seems to work well with touches, but not as good with Mouse. Try it and let me know if it behaves a bit better. This one should adjust the spinning speed dynamically:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SpinDrag : MonoBehaviour {

    float f_lastX = 0.0f;
    float f_difX = 0.5f;
    float f_steps = 0.0f;
    int i_direction = 1;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            f_difX = 0.0f;
        }
        else if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            f_difX = Mathf.Abs(f_lastX - Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"));

            if (f_lastX < Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"))
            {
                i_direction = -1;
                transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, -f_difX);
            }

            if (f_lastX > Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"))
            {
                i_direction = 1;
                transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, f_difX);
            }

            f_lastX = -Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
        }
        else
        {
            if (f_difX > 0.5f) f_difX -= 0.05f;
            if (f_difX < 0.5f) f_difX += 0.05f;

            transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, f_difX * i_direction);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It works perfectly and smoothly in editor, but the same thing happen on mobile, not smooth and a little bit late

Comment: What kind of device are you using to test with? It could be the processing/gpu power of your android device vs the tris and polys of your scene rendered. Maybe your device is simply getting overwhelmed? Unity3D has the guidelines posted in a few places (different per droid). For example, on my Pixel 3 I can run this smoothly with lots of polys/tris. However on my Samsung Galaxy S4 mini, the same scene is choppy.